# how to append result loop into list

Tags: python, django

How i can append every value that total_penjualan1 give?

this code will append just last total_penjualan1 result, what i must change?

```
agen = UserAddress.objects.filter(status="Agen")
for tampungini in agen:
    postingan_list2 = WriteStream.objects.filter(created_at__year=pkk, created_at__month=pk, nama_userr=tampungini.nama)
    for tampunglain in postingan_list2:
        get_transactions = api.getaddresstransaction(tampunglain.userr, tampunglain.address)
        amount = get_transactions['balance'].get('assets')[0].get('qty')
        total_penjualan1 = total_penjualan1 + amount            
    tampunganjumlah = []
    if total_penjualan1 >=1:
        tampunganjumlah.append(total_penjualan1)
        total_penjualan1 = 0
```

Comment: Pleas share your models, likely this can be done at the *database* side which is more efficient, and uses less bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `tampunganjumlah = []` to happen before the loop. As the code stands you're executing that on every iteration and erasing the contents of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
agen = UserAddress.objects.filter(status="Agen")
tampunganjumlah = []
for tampungini in agen:
    postingan_list2 = WriteStream.objects.filter(created_at__year=pkk, created_at__month=pk, nama_userr=tampungini.nama)
    for tampunglain in postingan_list2:
        get_transactions = api.getaddresstransaction(tampunglain.userr, tampunglain.address)
        amount = get_transactions['balance'].get('assets')[0].get('qty')
        total_penjualan1 = total_penjualan1 + amount            
        if total_penjualan1 >=1:
            tampunganjumlah.append(total_penjualan1)
        total_penjualan1 = 0
```